# $.callback() not calling calling list of callback method synchronously

Tags: jquery

Here is My code

```
    var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
    callbacks.add(BindRecipient);
    callbacks.add(dummy);
    callbacks.fire();

function BindRecipient()
{
//asynchrously  call to database for fetching some data.No callback is available here in this code.

}

    function dummy()
    {

    alert("Hazza");
    }
```

when I execute the code I get an alert before fetching data from first method call
I want the second method should be called only when BindRecipient has completed its execution